# unattended-upgrades conffile prompt

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-20.04, debian-buster

To enable `unattended-upgrades` for packages which can show `dpkg` config change menu, one has to configure `apt` and `dpkg` with these config options:

```
Dpkg::Options {
  "--force-confdef";
  "--force-confold";
};
```

These options should be added to a config fragment under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`; however, this will cause *any* `apt-get upgrade` command to not ask for config change selection.

My question is: does a method exist to enable `--force-confdef --force-confold` **only** for `unattended-upgrades`, short of modifying the `systemctl apt-daily-upgrade.service` unit file (ie: by adding a custom `APT_CONFIG` env var)? In other words, does exist a specific config file which is valid for `unattended-upgrades` only?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, but I expect this question to be relavant for Debian also.

Comment: How did you come up with the *premise*? I have used unattended-upgrades and manual upgrades alternately on Ubuntu just fine with only the latter running interactively and thus asking for conf choices.

Comment: @anx https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/debian/buster/README.md#supported-options-reference "Example - force dpkg to keep the old configuration files:" followed by "Note that unattended-upgrades detects this option, and ensures that packages with configuration prompts will never be held back."

Comment: @A.B Oh wow, the detection looks fairly solid actually. I never knew what it was supposed to do.. because it never skipped over packages with changed config for me. Now I wonder why..